# Make Reruns Build Everytime

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this `Makefile`

```
# Variables
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -c
ODUMP = objdump
ODFLAGS = -d

# Directories
OBJDIR := obj
TGTDIR := target
SRCDIR := src
DMPDIR := dump

# Sources list
SRCS := main.c kernel.c
# Sources location
VPATH := src:../headers

# Objects list
objects = $(notdir $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(SRCS))))
# Objects list with prefix
prefix_objs = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(objects))

# Target name
target = main

$(target) : $(objects)
    $(CC) -o $(TGTDIR)/$@ $(prefix_objs)

%.o: %.c | folders
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $<
    $(ODUMP) $(ODFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$@ > $(DMPDIR)/$@

folders:
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    mkdir -p $(TGTDIR)
    mkdir -p $(DMPDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(TGTDIR) $(DMPDIR)
```

I'm quite happy with this makefile. I have a few more tweaks, but the main problem statement is below.

> Every time I run `make` even with not changing any files, the entire project rebuilds (in this case, just main.c and kernel.c)

The output after running `make` is...

```
mkdir -p obj
mkdir -p target
mkdir -p dump
gcc -Wall -g -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c
objdump -d obj/main.o > dump/main.o
gcc -Wall -g -c -o obj/kernel.o src/kernel.c
objdump -d obj/kernel.o > dump/kernel.o
gcc -o target/main obj/main.o obj/kernel.o
```

then right after running `make` again it is...

```
mkdir -p obj
mkdir -p target
mkdir -p dump
gcc -Wall -g -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c
objdump -d obj/main.o > dump/main.o
gcc -Wall -g -c -o obj/kernel.o src/kernel.c
objdump -d obj/kernel.o > dump/kernel.o
gcc -o target/main obj/main.o obj/kernel.o
```

My file structure is as follows

```
| dump
| obj
| src ----
    | kernel.c
    | kernel.h
    | main.c
| target
.gitignore
Makefile
README.md
```

**Edit**
I set my target to `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c | folders` as well as `$(prefix_objs)/%.o: %.c | folders`

But got...

```
gcc -Wall -g -c   -c -o main.o src/main.c
gcc -Wall -g -c   -c -o kernel.o src/kernel.c
gcc -o target/main obj/main.o obj/kernel.o
gcc: error: obj/main.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: obj/kernel.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:27: main] Error 1
```

This is strange to me because the recipe is the same.

```
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $<
    $(ODUMP) $(ODFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$@ > $(DMPDIR)/$@
```

and definitely should not have produced the log above.

**Edit 2**
Okay. I got a little farther with this change.

```
$(target) : $(prefix_objs)
    $(CC) -o $(TGTDIR)/$@ $(prefix_objs)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c | folders
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    $(ODUMP) $(ODFLAGS) $@ > $(DMPDIR)/$@
```

I got...

```
mkdir -p obj
mkdir -p target
mkdir -p dump
gcc -Wall -g -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c
objdump -d obj/main.o > dump/obj/main.o
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create dump/obj/main.o: Directory nonexistent
make: *** [Makefile:31: obj/main.o] Error 2
```

This does bring me to my next issue. which I'll bring up in another post with nested directories and files in them. So just manually created the dump/obj folder just to get this working, and now, Only the relinking happens at the end every time i run make!

```
mkdir -p obj
mkdir -p target
mkdir -p dump/obj
gcc -o target/main obj/main.o obj/kernel.o
```

Comment: That's because your rule says that it will build `main.o` (for example), but the recipe actually builds `obj/main.o`.  So the next time make runs it will look to see if `main.o` exists, but it doesn't exist, so make builds it and again it builds `obj/main.o`, so the next time make runs it will look to see if `main.o` exists, but it doesn't exist, so make builds it again ...

Comment: If you ever write a make rule where the recipe doesn't build _exactly_ the file `$@` (not `../$@`, not `$(OBJDIR)/$@`, but _exactly_ `$@`) then you're almost 100% surely doing it wrong :).

Comment: I tried adding $(OBJDIR)/%.o as my target but got my edit @MadScientist

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you. that push in the right direction seemed to get that working. I'll make a new question with my next issue.

Comment: The relink happens every time for exactly the same reason: your link recipe is building `$(TGTDIR)/$@`.  As discussed above, `$(TGTDIR)/$@` is not exactly `$@`, so badness happens.